# Socket.io doesn't set CORS header(s)

Tags: http, node.js, websocket, socket.io, cors

I know this question has been asked a couple of times.
However, I can't get any those solutions to work.
I'm running a standard install of node.js and socket.io. (From yum on Amazon EC2)
The problem is that Chrome is falling back to xhr polling, and those requests require a working CORS configuration. However, I can't seem to get it to work. My web server is running on port 80, and node.js(socket.io) is running on port 81. I have tried to get socket.io to use a origin policy as you can see. I have also tried to use "* : *" as origin with no luck.
Here's my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(81, {origins: '*'});

io.configure( function(){
    io.set('origin', '*');
});
io.set("origins","*");

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    io.sockets.emit("message", "test");
res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('Hello Http');
    console.log("Message recieved!");
});
server.listen(82);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(client)  {
    console.log("New Connection");
});
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the syntax I had to use to get CORS working with socket.io:

```
io.set( 'origins', '*domain.com*:*' );
```

If it comes to it, use `console.log` to make sure you're entering this block of code in `Manager.prototype.handleHandshake` inside `./lib/manager.js`:

```
 if (origin) {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';

    if (req.headers.cookie) {
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true';
    }
  }
```

Comment: It didn't wok... I'm currently looking at using sockjs instead. But thanks anyways! :D

Comment: But since it does work for you, and I think that my install and configuration was wrong, I accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks. I still wouldn't mind debugging with you if you're up for it. Would need to see the HTTP headers.

Comment: I've looked at the HTTP headers numerous times, and the CORS headers aren't there. But I'm now using sockjs and it is working like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would recommend changing from '\*domain.com*:*' to 'http://domain.com:*' to make it more safe. Otherwise you could connect from domains such as "domain.com.example.com", "anotherdomain.com", etc.

Comment: FYI, `io.set()` is old (before 1.x).  I think it now requires options to be padded when creating the server.